# Is there C function to handle any shell history?

Tags: c, bash, macos, unix, zsh

I wrote a command-line tool in C/C++.
When it quit, I need to add a line to the current shell history.

For now, I wrap my tool in a shell command, using `history -w` and `history -r` for bash or `fc -W` and `fc -W` for zsh in order to add my line to the shell history (by appending a line to `$HISTFILE` then reloading it).

Is there a C function to handle history (append line, write file, reload history) for *any* *NIX shell, to avoid having to wrap my tool with specific shell stuffs ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no standard API for shell history. The `fc` command is specified in POSIX, but the `-w` option is a zsh extension.

Comment: Ok. And is there a POSIX way to append an arbitrary line to the current shell history (in the shell) ?

Comment: Many people use the [Gnu history library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html), which integrates nicely with [Gnu readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html). These can be installed on a Mac, but there is also an emulation layer using libedit, so the high-level programming interface is largely similar.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. POSIX specifies a least common denominator history feature. You can retrieve from history, but not modify it.

Comment: @rici The GNU history library looks like exactly what I need ! I'll take a look